# Need to update only one tuple, but this is updating the whole column in table

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I check if the the url is present first and see if he is up voting first time, if so then i will add the users repute to the upvoted column, but i want to add only to that url not to all urls, this code is adding to all all tuples in "upvotes" column, i want it to add only to a particular  tuple.

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
<?php
$c=$_GET['a'];// users name
$d=$_GET['b'];// usesrs id
$e=$_GET['c'];//  users repute
$ur=$_POST['url'];

// Create connection
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","repute system");
    if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
        echo "ERROR ".mysqli_connect_error();
} 

$sql = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM sites");
if (mysqli_num_rows($sql) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) 
    {

        if($ur == $row['URL'] && $d != $row['id'])
        {
        $ne = $row['upvotes'] + $e;   
        $sol = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE sites SET upvotes = $ne ");
        $bew = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO v_sites(teacher_id,URL,vote) VALUES ('$d','$ur','$e')");
        echo "Upvoted the site   ";
        echo $ur;       
       }
    }
} else {
    echo "Sorry before upvoting you have to block it first or you are trying to upvote your own report, in which you cant";
}
?>
</html>
```

Comment: you need a where clause in your update statement.

Comment: Which particular tuple is it supposed to update? How is it supposed to know which it is?

Comment: `UPDATE sites SET upvotes = $ne` yeah, that'd do it. As stated.... where's the where? Read up on update https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html

Comment: The tuple which has same url name as the one i will input in the html page(i am getting that by _post as u can see), so only if both match i want to update that row of url with added repute score to its upvotes @Barmar

Comment: My guess; `UPDATE sites SET upvotes = $ne WHERE id='$d'` if that works, let me know. I'll post an answer along with a few other tidbits. @razor

Comment: My table's name in sites it has 5 columns, which are URL,status,upvotes,downvotes, id  and all are varchar with 30 length

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All your rows are being updated because you are not using a `where` clause.

```
UPDATE sites SET upvotes = $ne
```

should be changed to:

```
UPDATE sites SET upvotes = $ne WHERE id='$d'
```

However, if `$ne` is also a string, `$ne` should also be quoted:

```
UPDATE sites SET upvotes = '$ne' WHERE id='$d'
```

Read up on `UPDATE`:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html

> *"My table's name in sites it has 5 columns, which are URL,status,upvotes,downvotes, id and all are varchar with 30 length"*

This tells me that `id` is VARCHAR also; not a good idea but that's up to you. It's best to use `int` for queries like this should all your id's be numerically-based.

Which is why using quotes `WHERE id='$d'` around the `$d` variable will be required.

---

Your present code is open to [**SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/). Use [**prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements), *they're much safer*.

Comment: the line `UPDATE sites SET upvotes = $ne WHERE id='$d'` updates the upvotes for the id of the user trying to upvote the block, thats not what i intended, i want the update for upvotes which has same url in db and same url input

Comment: @razor `WHERE id='$d' AND URL='$ur'` or `WHERE URL='$ur'`

Comment: @razor or `WHERE URL='$ur' AND id='$d'` - TBH, am having a bit of trouble wrapping my head around it. But try a few combinations as per the variables you're using.

Comment: @razor where are we at; still giving you trouble or has this been solved?

Comment: @razor Errr. ok. So you chose the other answer. Whatever.

Comment: Haha , you were more helpful

Answer (score 1):

You need a `WHERE` clause that matches the URL:

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, "UPDATE sites 
                              SET upvotes = upvotes + 1
                              WHERE url = ? AND id = ?";
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $ur, $d);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
```

You don't need the `SELECT` or `while` loop, since MySQL can find the matching rows and update them all by itself.

You also shouldn't have the `INSERT` query inside the loop, since it's inserting the same row each time.

And you should switch to prepared statements, as shown above, instead of inserting strings into your queries, since your code is subject to SQL injection.